# How to validate the contents of file against regular expresssion

Tags: java, validation

I want to validate the pdf file content with some regular expression.For that i converted the contents of the file into string object by using IOUtils(commons-io-2.2 jar) API. Below is my code.

```
FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(filePath);
    StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
    String encoding = "UTF-8";
    IOUtils.copy(fis, writer, encoding);
   String sourceText=writer.toString();
```

After preparing my sourceText i am validating the sourceText with a regular expression like below

```
    Pattern srcPattern = Pattern.compile("\\btax", 2);
    Matcher taxMatcher = srcPattern.matcher(this.sourceText);
    if (taxMatcher.find()) {
        isTaxRelevant = true;
    } else{isTaxRelevant = false;
            }
```

In the original PDF document i have statements with string tax , but the above code is always returning false. When i am printing the source text i am seeing the text as a binary data.
I suspect due to that reason only it is not able to validate against a regular expression. Is there any chance to validate my contents of the PDF file against regular expression.

Comment: You are basically doing the same as trying to open a PDF file in notepad. It doesn't work!!! You'll need to use a library that can read PDF's.

Comment: I need a solution to read any kind of files (pdf's,html,aspx).My code should be generic.

Comment: *read any kind of file* doesn't make sense in a programming context. Programs don't have eyes, and certainly are not able to "read" in the human sense

Comment: Basically my input file can be of any type . I can not use specific libraries for each and every type of file.

Comment: So, you basically want some magic library that can read any file format that has ever existed. I guess this magic library can look at a photo or video and understand the content? I don't think so ;). Unless you are some guru in artificial intelligence (which I highly doubt) you'll need to narrow down the scope.

Comment: Thats great reply , thanks for that.